# How To Solve "The file '/CRM/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx' does not exist" Exception

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I keep coming accross that exeption in log file. 
When I googled for it I found many other ones that came accros the same problem and did not find a solution.

```
Process: w3wp |Organization:fb65d5a5-f607-405c-a385-471af737e077 |Thread:   96 |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 2d63ad1c-475e-4c60-a35a-0ba437c1781c | ErrorInformation.LogError  ilOffset = 0x17
    at ErrorInformation.LogError()  ilOffset = 0x17
    at ErrorInformation..ctor(Exception exception, Uri requestUrl, Boolean logError, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x1F5
    at ErrorInformation..ctor(Exception exception, Uri requestUrl, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x5
    at MainApplication.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs eventArguments)  ilOffset = 0x81
    at EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()  ilOffset = 0x26
    at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)  ilOffset = 0x85
    at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)  ilOffset = 0x5C
    at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)  ilOffset = 0x16A
    at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)  ilOffset = 0x4B
```

### MSCRM Error Report:

> Error: The file '/CRM/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx' does not
>   exist.
>
> Error Message: The file '/CRM/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx'
>   does not exist.
>
> Error Details: The file '/CRM/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx'
>   does not exist.
>
> Source File: Not available
>
> Line Number: Not available
>
> Request URL:
>   crmlink/CRM/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx?AttachmentType=1001&AttachmentId=379176b3-eabb-e411-944f-005056b331b9

```
Stack Trace Info: [HttpException: The file '/CRM/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx' does not exist.]
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail, no one will care to look at it, if you don't care to explain it better! 
What happens, when it happens, why do you think it happens, what have you done so far to prevent it from happening.

Comment: So you are saying you are seeing "The file '/CRM/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx' does not exist” in the Dynamics CRM TRACE file? Is this causing an error or an issue in your environment.

Comment: edited and added trace

Comment: I know seems a random answer, but can you try to clean temp files and cookies on your computer.